# How to allow more characters in the validation of an email field?

Tags: laravel, validation

I'm having a problem validating the length of an email in Laravel 5.4.
In the migration I created the email field by default, and it was done correctly in DB as `varchar (191) utf8mb4_unicode_ci`.
In the frontend there is no problem with validation, but in backend it only allows up to 73 characters.

In Controller on save and update methods, I tried:

```
$this->validate($request, [
    // ...
    'email' => 'nullable|email',
    // ....
]);
```

```
$this->validate($request, [
    // ...
    'email' => 'nullable|email|max:191',
    // ....
]);
```

View form input:

```
{!! Form::label('email', 'Email:') !!}
{!! Form::email('email', null, ['class' => 'form-control' . ($errors->has('email') ? ' is-invalid' : ''), 'maxlength' => 191]) !!}

@if ($errors->has('email'))
    <span class="invalid-feedback">{{ $errors->first('email') }}</span>
@endif
```

This passes the validation (73 characters):
*aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa@test.com*

but this, or longer ones, do not pass the validation  (74 characters):
*aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa@test.com*
(also I tried other characters, not just aaa, just in case it's not the lenght with no luck)
[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RFC specifications for email and what is technically valid within one.

> 1. An e-mail address consists of local part and domain separated by an at sign (@) character (RFC 2822 3.4.1).
> 2. The local part may consist of alphabetic and numeric characters, and the following characters: !, #, $, %, &, ', *, +, -, /, =, ?, ^, _, `, {, |, } and ~, possibly with dot separators (.), inside, but not at the start, end or next to another dot separator (RFC2822 3.2.4).
> 3. The local part may consist of a quoted string—that is, anything within quotes ("), including spaces (RFC 2822 3.2.5).
> 4. Quoted pairs (such as @) are valid components of a local part, though an obsolete form from RFC 822 (RFC 2822 4.4).
> 5. The maximum length of a local part is 64 characters (RFC 2821 4.5.3.1).
> 6. A domain consists of labels separated by dot separators (RFC1035 2.3.1).
> 7. Domain labels start with an alphabetic character followed by zero or more alphabetic characters, numeric characters or the hyphen (-), ending with an alphabetic or numeric character (RFC 1035 2.3.1).
> 8. The maximum length of a label is 63 characters (RFC 1035 2.3.1).
> 9. The maximum length of a domain is 255 characters (RFC 2821 4.5.3.1).
> 10. The domain must be fully qualified and resolvable to a type A or type MX DNS address record (RFC 2821 3.6).

So in conclusion if you would want to use a longer one you should add your custom email rule which will avoid some of this checks.

Comment: Ahh! Yes, it was the length of the local part. As a note, for some reason Laravel validates up to 74 and not up to 64 characters as the standard says. I also tested the domain part and allows up to 63 each label as in the standard. I only have up to 191 on total domain part to not touch the DB. Thanks @nakov!